# NullPointerException when creating a Scheduler Bean with Spring

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to use Spring to create a scheduler.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class MyScheduler {


  @Autowired
  MyBusinessService businessService;


  @Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
  public void myCronMethod() {

  }
}
```

During application startup I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.resolveSchedulerBean(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:281)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.finishRegistration(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:221)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:200)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In the *ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor* the holder is null:

```
NamedBeanHolder<T> holder = ((AutowireCapableBeanFactory) this.beanFactory).resolveNamedBean(schedulerType);
```

The *schedulerType* is:

```
interface org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler
```

The application is a JSF application. Im using java 8 and spring version 4.3.6, however with Ant and without dependency management, so missing libraries or a library mismatch is a possibility.

Comment: It is a Java program and an Exception from the standard library, I think the tag was adequate!?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it without Java either

Comment: Go ahead, tag it java, keyboard, mouse, monitor, electricity, eyes, brain... server is starting, spring is initializing, jsf is not doing anything yet.

Comment: Could you please change cron pattern to this: `* * * ? * *` - it is for every second

Answer (score 1):

Having just had the same error in a Kotlin application, my workaround was to manually add a `TaskScheduler` to my application configuration:

The Java example is taken [from here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler).

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler(){
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler
      = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix(
      "ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

My Kotlin version is

```
@Bean
fun threadPoolTaskScheduler()
    = ThreadPoolTaskScheduler().apply {
        setPoolSize(5)
        setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler")
}
```

(I've not yet tried it, but I believe upgrading to Spring 5 will also fix this - [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/edc62be2310acbce918f742bb6960fcd69d413d2) throws an Exception where the null pointer would have been generated.)